# Gmail Contact List Safety

Tags: account-security, spam, gmail, email-spoofing

How can I know that my Gmail is spoofed or sending spams to other people I sent email to them before? I don't have clear signs of that especially my contact list is empty but I'm afraid this may happen later as I clicked on a strange link in a mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

If someone spoofs your Gmail account, there is no possible way for you to know that. That would be like being able to know if I introduce myself to others as Ali Zahy. The receivers would know if they inspected the headers of those emails, though.

You might be able to determine if your actual account was used to send emails by looking at your sent and deleted folders. But if the malicious emails were permanently deleted, there would be no way for you to know. But, again, the proof is on the receiver's side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can a bad guy get the contact list easily? Mustn't he get permission from Google to get it? And what are the other ways that may make my address get spoofed.

Comment: In order to get your contact list, the attacker must gain access to your account. Spoofing email addresses is very simple. With the right tool, you just enter your email address as the sending address. It's really quite simple. I can send anyone an email that says it comes from alizahy@gmail.com, for instance.

Comment: Do all the apps downloaded from the play store have access to the account? Or they must require that in their permissions before installation?

Comment: They must request permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 
Also, I heard the term 'bounce back'; is that sent to me when the spam is sent?
Cannot the attacker delete the mail from the sent folder before I see it? 
One last thing; do you see any precautions that can be taken to secure my account after I clicked this link knowing that I haven't recevied a complaint from anyone? Or should I change my email address?

Comment: Yes, the attacker can delete the email from the folder. I said that in my answer. Look at your Gmail settings and look for all the apps that are connected. Disconnect anything you do not recognise, then just change your password, if you are concerned.

Comment: So if found no connected apps to email, this means I'm secure?

Comment: That means no malicious app has connected to your account without your permission